# Xamarin.IOS FFimageloading doesn't load

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ffimageloading

I have a problem with FFImageLoading with ios: the CachedIamages doesn't load.
But with Android all works well.
I have researched a lot on the web but i have found notthing usefull.
I have already update to the last prereleased but notthing.
any ideas?
Sorry for bad english guys.

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70722/ffimageloading-forms-image-is-not-loading-in-ios) and [here](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/239)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two solutions to FFImage problems; 1- i solved it's issues through code. 2- i switched FFImage to SDWebImage (https://components.xamarin.com/view/sdwebimage). I've faced many problems when using FFImage, i've figured some stuff out but it's kinda hard to explain from here.I wanted to have an alternative solution so i tried to use SDWebImage and SDWebImage works very well, you should give it a shot.